# printing an object of a type lacking read syntax in ELisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

[Some types](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Type.html#Window-Type) in ELisp lack a read syntax. Printing them only results in a string with a hash-table like name in it:

```
(print (selected-window))
#<window 3 on test.el>
```

but they cannot be examined like a hash:

```
(require 'subr-x)
(hash-table-keys (selected-window))
hash-table-keys: Wrong type argument: hash-table-p, #<window 3 on test.el>
```

Sometimes it would help to understand a program if it was possible to dump all internal fields/settings/properties of such objects at various points of the execution, in edebug for example. Can this be done, either using an existing function, or by some enumeration trick?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, [*hash* notation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Printed-Representation.html) has *nothing* to do with [*hash* tables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hash-Tables.html).

Second, objects like [windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Windows.html) have *many* internals. Just look at the manual I linked to.

Third, as far as "enumeration trick" goes, your best bet is [`apropos`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Help-Functions.html): it will give you all the interesting symbols that match a pattern. Try <kbd>C-h a</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks! I think I was a bit unclear, sorry. I am l trying to determine whether it is programmatically possible to inspect such objects, without having to manually tailor a print function for each type. Like Data::Dumper in Perl for example - it accepts any object of any type and prints all internal structures and fields. In the case of the window type, it would be wonderful to see a window object’s internal fields progress when the window changes, when you (set-window-dedicated..) etc.

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that in ELisp.